# Site-to-site VPN between Azure Virtual Network and a Cisco RV016

Tags: vpn, ipsec, azure, tunnel, virtual-network

I'm attempting to configure a Cisco RV016 router to connect to an Azure Virtual Network to create a site-to-site VPN, but it's not working.

I'm aware that a Cisco RV016 is not in the [list of officially supported devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156075.aspx), however it does appear to meet the requirements listed on the same page.

The information I'm getting in the Cisco logs is:

```
(g2gips0) #87: initiating Main Mode
(g2gips0) #87: [Tunnel Negotiation Info] >>> Initiator Send Main Mode 1st packet
packet from 137.xxx.xxx.xxx:500: ignoring informational payload, type NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
```

And the only error I get on Azure is:

```
Unable to establish the cross-premise tunnel for MyNetwork. Previous 
state: Initializing. Current state: Not Connected. 5/8/2013 10:27:47 AM
```

The config on my Cisco RV016 is this:

```
Local Security Gateway Type:  IP Only
IP Address:                   <ip addr of the RV016>
Local Security Group Type:    Subnet
IP Address:                   192.168.0.0
Subnet mask:                  255.255.255.0

Remote Security Gateway Type: IP Only
IP Address:                   <Azure Gateway IP Address>
Remote Security Group Type:   Subnet
IP Address:                   10.1.0.0 <address space that I've configured in Azure Virtual Network>
Subnet Mask:                  255.255.240.0 <i.e. 10.1.0.0/20>

IPSec Setup
Keying Mode:             IKE with Preshared key
Phase 1 DH Group:        Group 2 - 1024 bit
Phase 1 Encryption:      AES-256
Phase 1 Authentication:  SHA1
Phase 1 SA lifetime:     28800
Perfect Forward Secrecy: false
Phase 2 DH Group:        Group 2 - 1024 bit
Phase 2 Encryption:      AES-256
Phase 2 Authentication:  SHA1
Phase 2 SA lifetime:     3600
Preshared Key:           <copied from Azure generated shared key>

Advanced
Aggressive Mode:     False
Compress:            False
Keep-alive:          True
AH Hash Algorithm:   False
NetBIOS Broadcast:   False
NAT Traversal:       False
Dead Peer Detection: False
Tunnel Backup:       Not configured
Split DNS:           Not configured
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Can you share the solution or fix if so?

Comment: No sorry, I gave up and used a Cisco ASA 5505 instead!